# PHP: get form's name

Tags: php, html

***What a problem***

I'm new in php, and I faced a very trivial problem: *how to get form's name in php?*

***What I've tried:***

```
$name = $form['name'];
print_r($name); // echo stuff like SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => feedback [description] =>...
```

***Question:***

How can I get only name of the form?

Comment: `$name = $form->attributes()->name;` Please read [the documentation](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Comment: Try `$name = $_POST['name'];` which is "one" way of doing it, assuming you're using a POST request. You can also use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` yet I tend to think that [Amal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19745089/1415724) is what's to be used. Try posting your full code so we can see exactly what you have. 2 lines of code is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting the SimpleXML object from, but to access the `name` attribute, you can use the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
echo $xml->attributes()->name;
```

Comment: Why just not use `$_POST['name']` / `$_GET['name']` ?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: I think the OP is trying to access the attribute `name` from the SimpleXML object. He just listed `$_POST['name']` as one method he tried.

Comment: @AmalMurali That's what I thought as well. [Notice my mention?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745076/php-get-forms-name#comment29339437_19745076) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To identify the submitted form, you can use:

- A hidden input field OR.
- The name or value of the submit button.

The name of the form is not sent to the server as part of the POST data.